# C# Regex General Matching

Tags: c#, regex, match

I have the message as below and I have 2 regex targetted on this.

For the regex rh, it worked well. While for regex rh1, I can't figure out and the match should return something like `"{{0:0.00}%,{ABND,1000},/,{OFRD,1002}}"` instead of `"{0:0.00"` which going to be replaced with final value.

I would appreciate for any advise.

```
T.Format = "T1 Message: {{0:0.00}%,{ABND,1000},/,{OFRD,1002}}";


Regex rh = new Regex(@"{{(.*?)}(.*?),{(.*?),(.*?)},(.*?),{(.*?),(.*?)}}");
Match mh = rh.Match(T.Format);
Regex rh1 = new Regex(@"{(.*?)}");
Match mh1 = rh1.Match(T.Format);
decimal decReturn = 0;
string h1 = mh.Groups[1].Value.ToString();
string h2 = mh.Groups[2].Value.ToString();
string h3 = mh.Groups[3].Value.ToString();
string h4 = mh.Groups[4].Value.ToString();
string h5 = mh.Groups[5].Value.ToString();
string h6 = mh.Groups[6].Value.ToString();
string h7 = mh.Groups[7].Value.ToString();

switch (h5)
{
   case "+": decReturn = 0; break;
   case "-": decReturn = 0; break;
   case "*": decReturn = 0; break;
   case "/": decReturn = Convert.toInt32(h7) > 0 ? Convert.toInt32(h4) / Convert.toInt32(h7) * 100 : 0 * 100;
                            break;
   default: throw new Exception("invalid logic");
}

string strReplace = mh1.Groups[1].Value.ToString();
string strReturn = string.Empty;
strReturn = Convert.ToString(decReturn);
strReturn = Convert.ToString(T.Format).Replace(strReplace, strReturn);
```

Comment: You'll have to refine your question. The code doesn't say what you are trying to achieve. Can you provide us with an expected input and the expected output to that input?

Comment: Anyways; is this homework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the problem:

```
{(.*?)}
    ^
  This makes a lazy match, one character at time
```

Instead replace with:

```
{(.*)}
```